# print to xcode simulator

Tags: swift, xcode

Hi I have some code that gets coordinates and dates and times but it only shows the result in the console output window. Can someone guide me to best solution to display the output in the simulator. tableview or what should I use. I basically just need a start

Comment: You can use a label to display some text on the simulator's screen

Comment: `I basically just need a start`. Indeed. Start with a 'hello world' example. It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can add a label to your view and change your label text to what you want to print.

or

you can show an alert view with the content of what you want to print.

Here's an example to add an alert view (sender being the view controller calling this method).

```
func showSimpleAlert(_ title:String, message:String, sender:AnyObject) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    sender.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then you just need to convert the object you want to print (Date, Double, etc.) to a String object

EDIT: When you call the alert view, here's what you can do:

```
// Assuming we're in the ViewController class

let alertString = String(format:"one: %@\ntwo: %@\nthree: %@\nfour: %@\nfive: %@", 
                         Formatter.string(from: houses.one),
                         Formatter.string(from: houses.two),
                         Formatter.string(from: houses.three),
                         Formatter.string(from: houses.four),
                         Formatter.string(from: houses.five))

showSimpleAlert("Debug print", message: alertString, sender: self)
```

Comment: i have added the code and added print command but see nothing in the simulator just blank white screen

Comment: print("one", formatter.string(from: houses.one))
            print("two", formatter.string(from: houses.two))
            print("three", formatter.string(from: houses.three))
            print("four", formatter.string(from: houses.four))
            print("five", formatter.string(from: houses.five))

these all get printed to console output but would like to see them in the simulator screen

Comment: seem to be getting an error: use of unresolved identifier 'alertString'

Comment: formatter.string return a String right? I edited my answer again

Answer (score 0):

For detailed output of your print logs, use a developer only trick. Add a tap gesture (which is only known to you) and continuous 3 taps in that area within 2 seconds should invoke the hidden feature from your app where you display all the logs in a `UITextView`. You should implement a custom logger class which logs the required outputs to a plain text file which should be used to recall the logs.

Adding a UILabel will impact the UI of your app and you may not want these logs to be available to all the users. Hence having a hidden area to check the logs would be an elegant approach.

Comment: its not logs that gets printed but results from my code that gets displayed in the output window.